# Remove multiple punctuations followed by punctuations javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex, expression

Am trying to remove the ,|- symbols I have tried the following.

```js
var s="very good ,. hello |. how -. are. you|";
s = s.replace(/,+(?=\.)/g, "");

console.log(s)
```

Am not able to remove any punctuations which are followed by fullstop or followed by multiple symbols.Can any one help me out 
expected result

```
 very good . hello . how . are. you|
```

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: very good , hello . how - are.

Comment: Try `s = s.replace(/([.,|-])+/g, "$1")`. However, your requirements are still not clear to me.

Comment: You did not include | and - in the regexp

Comment: _"any punctuations which are followed by fullstop"_ is clear, but what do you mean by "_followed by multiple symbols_"?

Comment: Please, put the result you want using your example. This will help everyone understand.

Comment: updated expected result in question

Comment: Ok, try `s = s.replace(/[,|-]+(\.)/g, "$1")` - https://regex101.com/r/Hr1bBP/2, also my above comment should work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove all punctuation that are preceded by punctuation, use this. I am unsure what you are expecting. I have included two solutions, one to keep only the last symbol, and one to keep only the first...

```js
var s="very good ,. hello |. how -. are. you|";
console.log("First try: "  + s.replace(/([,|.-])[\s]*[,|.-]+/g, "$1"));
console.log("Second try: " + s.replace(/[,|.-]+[\s]*([,|.-])/g, "$1"));
```

Comment: remove was the name of the variable in OP before it got edited.

Comment: Have edited string please check I want to make punctuation empty if is followed by any other punctuation

Comment: I have added 'you |' in  question just check it once as it is not followed by fullstop

Comment: Yeh, see the second try.

Comment: Hi if there is space between , . how can i do then to remove , and space

Comment: I've added the optional space to the answer. Please do not change too much from the original question, it will make it harder to understand for people coming here for answers later.

Answer (score 0):

You're very close, add the other punctuations in a character class:

```js
var s="very good ,. hello |. how -. are. you|";
s = s.replace(/[,.|-]+(?=\.)/g, "");

console.log(s)
```

Comment: Have edited string please check I want to make punctuation empty if is followed by any other punctuation

Comment: @shansetivikas: You aren't very clear, my regex remove the punctuations that are before a dot, as specified in question. If it isn't what you want, please edit yoyr question and add test cases and expected result for each.

Comment: @shansetivikas: Is it OK? It gives `very good . hello . how . are. you|` as wanted, isn't it?